# Getting correct date from FSCalendar

Tags: swift, fscalendar

I have been looking around a lot but found no real solution to this one.

I use `FSCalendar` and `didSelectDate` is giving the wrong date.

The only fix for this that I've found is using this code that I'm using right now:

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {        
    let newDate = date.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT(for: date)))
        currentDateVc = newDate
    }
```

This means if I choose the **22th in February** I get `"2022/02/22 - 00:00:00"`, here is the issue, I get the correct day but not time. And in my app I need the correct time as well. Is there anyway I can fix this? Maybe with `CalendarComponents` for time from `Date()`?

Comment: FSCalendar is for a date only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to compose the date from `FSCalendar` and the current `datetime` to make a new `Date`. One way to do this:

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
    let now = Date()
    let cal = Calendar.current

    let newDate = cal.date(bySettingHour: cal.component(.hour, from: now),
                                  minute: cal.component(.minute, from: now),
                                  second: cal.component(.second, from: now),
                                      of: date)!

    currentDateVc = newDate
}
```

***Side note:** It's better to use features of the calendar/datetime library to get your local time instead of adding seconds from GMT to your date time data. You'll avoid mysterious errors in the future.*